# How can I build a functioning time recorder (clock-in and clock-out)

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I would like some help to write a python script that will record the time & date when I get to work and turn on my computer and the time I turn it off.

So far, I've only managed to do the following:
- on one script, I wrote a code to record the time I arrive in the morning (output in a csv file)
- on a separate script, I copied the same code but I run it in the evening (output in another csv file)
- thirdly, a 3rd script uses the pandas library to combine to two files

1. Clockin code:

Code:

```
def clockin():
    import datetime
    import time
    currentDate = datetime.date.today()
    currentTime_in = datetime.datetime.now().time()

    import csv
    with open('Clockin.csv', mode ='a') as Clockin:
        Clockin_writer = csv.writer(Clockin, delimiter = ',', quotechar ='"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        Clockin_writer.writerow([currentDate, currentTime_in])
```

2. Clock-out code:

Code:

```
def clockout():
    import datetime
    import time

    currentDate = datetime.date.today()
    currentTime_out = datetime.datetime.now().time()

    import csv
    with open('Clockout.csv', mode ='a') as Clockout:
        Clockout_writer = csv.writer(Clockout, delimiter = ',', quotechar ='"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        Clockout_writer.writerow([currentDate, currentTime_out])
```

3. Combining the two files:

Code:

```
def timesheet():
    import pandas as pd

    a = pd.read_csv("Clockin.csv")
    b = pd.read_csv("Clockout.csv")
    merged = a.merge(b)
    merged.to_csv("timesheet.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Please, do not use capitalized words as variable names. Capitalized names are reserved for class names in Python.

Comment: Additionally, imports should be at the start of the files.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to edit your question to describe what is actually failing for you.

Without knowing that, the general problem I see is that there's nothing to make sure that you match the correct time out with each particular time in.

It sounds like you intend to run your 'in' and 'out' scripts manually, or perhaps trigger them from login and logout events. But it's very easy to end up with missed or extra entries: You might forget and clock 'in' twice, or you might do multiple logins (or shells, if triggering that way), or your system might crash before you can do the expected clock 'out'.

When that happens, your two log files will be out of sync, and I'm pretty sure a plain panda merge (no left_on and right_on, or 'on', parameters) will just pair records off in order. That would not work unless they're in perfect sync.

A safer way is to write all the events to the same file, adding a third column that says either "IN" or "OUT". Then when you want to merge, you're at least guaranteed that the next "OUT" after each "IN" is the best one to use. It's easy to spot errors by scanning that file visually. A program can also easily check whether the file alternates INs and OUTs, and report exactly where the problem is if not.

I've done that for a similar task for a long time. Logging is triggered when I open and close each *nix shell window, so I may have multiple "in"s active at once; but it's still pretty easy to pick out the right range -- just take the first from any run of IN events, and the last of the nearest following run of OUT events.

Of course, even then you could clock in on Monday, and somehow fail to clock at all until Friday, when you clock out. With almost any solution, that will look like you worked 24 hours a day all week. If you're worried about that case, your merge can issue a warning for any work-shifts that seem too long.

Hope that helps. If not, please clarify the question by saying exactly what the current problem is.